# svg background IE and positioning issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg

Hi I have two svg's that I use to create a banner like image in my header. One sits to the left, the other the right. In IE, they just sit in the middle, how do I fix this?

```
#header-left {
    background-position: 10% -7%;
    min-height: 250px;
    background-size: inherit;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/banner-left-side-02-02.svg);
    max-height: 250px;
}

#header-right {
    background-color: rgba(169, 48, 37, 0);
    background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/banner-right-side-01.svg);
    background-position: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 250px;
}
```

If you would like to see the problem..., http://dronework.com.au/

Answer (score 0):

Is this close to what you are looking for?

```css
#header-left {
    background-image: url(http://dronework.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/banner-left-side-02-02.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: silver;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}

#header-right {
    background-image: url(http://dronework.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/banner-right-side-01.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: lightgray;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    float: right;
    background-position: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-left"></div>
<div id="header-right"></div>
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work at all. Take a look on the website. I basically want it to look the same as it does in Chrome on IE